# Why is this form validator function not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a signup form inside a React functional component,

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-robinson-g8y3n

The validator function returns a promise. If every field of the form is correct, it returns a resolve else a reject. If the validator returns a resolve then I perform an API Call ( Here I have just console logged "API Request Sent" ) else I console log the errors.

Even If I perform an invalid form input ( especially the email ), the API Request is still sent.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  avatar: {
    margin: '10px auto',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  paper: {
    width: '50vw',
    margin: '1rem auto 3rem auto',
    padding: '2rem',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    backdropFilter: 'blur(10px)',
    
  },
  align: {
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
  },
  field: {
    width: '100%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    marginTop: '15px',
  },
  form: {
    width: '80%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    margin: '1rem auto',
  },
}));


export default function Signup() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let [error, setError] = useState('');
  
  let data = {};
  function setData(event, key) {
    data[key] = event.target.value;
  }

  function validator() {
    console.log(data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const exp = RegExp('w+@example.com').test(data.email);
      console.log(exp);
      if (!exp) {
        setError('Email Not Valid! Please use Institute Email ID');
      }
      if (data.password !== data.password2) {
        setError('Password Does Not Match!');
      }
      console.log(error);
      if (error !== '') {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve('ok');
      }
    });
  }

  const onSignup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validator()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('API Request Sent');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('The errors are: '+ error)
      });
  };

  return (
    
      <form className={classes.form}>
        <TextField
          required
          className={classes.field}
          id="outlined-required"
          label="User Name"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(event) => setData(event, 'username')}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          type="email"
          className={classes.field}
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Email"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setData(event, 'email');
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          className={classes.field}
          id="outlined-required"
          label="First Name"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(event) => setData(event, 'first_name')}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          className={classes.field}
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Last Name"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(event) => setData(event, 'last_name')}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          type="password"
          className={classes.field}
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Password"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(event) => setData(event, 'password')}
        />
        <TextField
          required
          type="password"
          className={classes.field}
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Confirm Password"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setData(event, 'password2');
          }}
        />
        <Button
          className={classes.field}
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          onClick={(e) => onSignup(e)}
        >
          Sign Up
        </Button>
      </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not just a link to an external resource that might not be available or change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to change a lot of your code. First off, you were using a plain object to handle your form state, instead of using `useState`.

```
  let data = {};
  function setData(event, key) {
    data[key] = event.target.value;
  }
```

I changed that to utilize `useState` where I also initialized all of the field values in the object right off the bat.

```
  const [data, setDataForm] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    password: "",
    password2: ""
  });

  const setData = (e, key) => {
    setDataForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: e.target.value }));
  };
```

Not only that, you also weren't setting the value field on all of your input fields, which I added like so:

```
<TextField
    required
    className={classes.field}
    id="outlined-required"
    label="User Name"
    variant="outlined"
    onChange={(event) => setData(event, "username")}
    value={data.username}
/>
```

For the last portion, specifically the error handling, I added a local `err` variable that handles recording what type of error it was. React state updates are asynchronous, and aren't guaranteed to finish before your code executes.

For example, where you do this:

```
  if (!exp) {
    setError('Email Not Valid! Please use Institute Email ID');
  }
  if (data.password !== data.password2) {
    setError('Password Does Not Match!');
  }
  console.log(error);
  if (error !== '') {
    reject(error);
  } else {
    resolve('ok');
  }
```

`error` might not be up to date when you attempt to reject it below. Therefore, using a local variable guarantees that you will always catch the error. At the very end you can then set the error to your `error` state.

Full code below (*minus styles*)

```
export default function Signup() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let [error, setError] = useState("");

  const [data, setDataForm] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    password: "",
    password2: ""
  });

  const setData = (e, key) => {
    setDataForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: e.target.value }));
  };

  function validator() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let err = "";
      const exp = RegExp("w+@btech.nitdgp.ac.in|nitdgp.ac.in").test(data.email);

      if (!exp) {
        err = "Email Not Valid! Please use Institute Email ID";
      } else if (data.password === "" || data.password !== data.password2) {
        err = "Password Does Not Match!";
      }

      if (err !== "") {
        setError(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve("ok");
      }
    });
  }

  const onSignup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validator()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("API Request Sent");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("The errors are: " + error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form className={classes.form}>
      <TextField
        required
        className={classes.field}
        id="outlined-required"
        label="User Name"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(event) => setData(event, "username")}
        value={data.username}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        type="email"
        className={classes.field}
        id="outlined-required"
        label="Email"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setData(event, "email");
        }}
        value={data.email}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        className={classes.field}
        id="outlined-required"
        label="First Name"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(event) => setData(event, "first_name")}
        value={data.first_name}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        className={classes.field}
        id="outlined-required"
        label="Last Name"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(event) => setData(event, "last_name")}
        value={data.last_name}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        type="password"
        className={classes.field}
        id="outlined-required"
        label="Password"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(event) => setData(event, "password")}
        value={data.password}
      />
      <TextField
        required
        type="password"
        className={classes.field}
        id="outlined-required"
        label="Confirm Password"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setData(event, "password2");
        }}
        value={data.password2}
      />
      <Button
        className={classes.field}
        color="primary"
        variant="contained"
        onClick={(e) => onSignup(e)}
      >
        Sign Up
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```